# jtable - how to set gap between columns

Tags: swing, jtable

Is there a way to add a gap between JTable columns or rows?
(without using a cell renderer)

Comment: for discussing the usability/standards whatever of this forum, there's the meta forum :-)

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/163188).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

look at setIntercellSpacing and/or setRow/ColumnMargin. Okay, looked up the methods:

```
// set gap between rows, api in JTable
table.setRowMargin(int)
// set gap between columns, api in TableColumnModel
table.getColumnModel().setColumnMargin(int)
// convenience for setting both row and column gaps
table.setIntercellSpacing(Dimension)
```

Comment: hi, this puts the gaps inside the cells. I want the columns to be detached a bit. is there a way to put the gap outside the cell?

Comment: no, it doesn't - as you can verify by f.i. selecting a row: the selection color is the "inside", aka the part rendered by the rendering componnet, the area between is the part rendered by the table itself (in its background color). What else do you want to achieve?